# How to display the details of my url params in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Why my code doesn't display the result coming from my API in ExpressJs?

It successfully prints the details in my console but doesn't display on my page.

What could be the reason why this is not working?

This is my console.
[image: pic]

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{result.First_Name}}</h1>
    <h1>{{result.First_Name}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Memb_ID: this.$route.params.Memb_ID,
      result: {}
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$http
      .get("http://localhost:9000/api/user/" + this.Memb_ID)
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.result = data.body;
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

**EDIT**: I added the screenshot of my console.

Comment: What **exactly** does your console show? A screenshot would be good

Comment: @Phil Hi, I've added the screenshot. Thanks

Comment: Oh, never mind. I just realised you aren't using an arrow function so your `this` reference is incorrect. It's an easy fix

Comment: @Phil how could I fix it?

Comment: I added a duplicate link for you but it's as simple as changing `.then(function(data) { ... })` to `.then(data => { ... })`

Comment: @Phil no, still it doesn't display the data

Comment: Ok, looking closer, the _data_ in your response is an array so you'd need `{{ result[0].First_Name }}` or something like that. I've added another link that should help